# MediaElement.js issue when use display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, mediaelement.js

i have a website in wordpress, wordpress for video use the MediaElement.js library, now i want insert the video on a popup so when click the button are opened in a popup, but i have a problem .

when open the popup the width and height of video are high , this only when use a css "display:none;" for hide the video by default.

this is the correct code when video are ok.

```
 <div id="cont-video2" class="" style="max-height: 413px;">
    <div class=""> x </div>
    <div style="width: 640px; " class="wp-video">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script>document.createElement('video');</script><![endif]-->
        <span class="mejs-offscreen">Video Player</span>
        <div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container svg wp-video-shortcode mejs-video" tabindex="0" role="application" aria-label="Video Player" style="width: 640px; height: 360px;">
            <div class="mejs-inner">
                <div class="mejs-mediaelement">
                    <video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-219-1" width="640" height="360" preload="metadata" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4?_=1">
                        <source type="video/mp4" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4?_=1"><a href="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4</a>
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div class="mejs-layers">
                    <div class="mejs-poster mejs-layer" style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
                    <div class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
                        <div class="mejs-overlay-loading"><span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer" style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                        <div class="mejs-overlay-error"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer mejs-overlay-play" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                        <div class="mejs-overlay-button"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mejs-controls" style="display: block; visibility: hidden;">
                    <div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-play">
                        <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-time mejs-currenttime-container" role="timer" aria-live="off"><span class="mejs-currenttime">00:00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-time-rail" style="width: 496px;"><span class="mejs-time-total mejs-time-slider" style="width: 486px;"><span class="mejs-time-buffering" style="display: none;"></span><span class="mejs-time-loaded" style="width: 9.81818px;"></span><span class="mejs-time-current" style="width: 0px;"></span><span class="mejs-time-handle" style="left: -5px;"></span><span class="mejs-time-float"><span class="mejs-time-float-current">00:00</span><span class="mejs-time-float-corner"></span></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-time mejs-duration-container"><span class="mejs-duration">00:29</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-button mejs-volume-button mejs-mute">
                        <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Muto" aria-label="Muto"></button><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mejs-volume-slider" style="display: none;" aria-label="volumeSlider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuetext="80%" role="slider" tabindex="0"><span class="mejs-offscreen">Use Up/Down Arrow keys to increase or decrease volume.</span><div class="mejs-volume-total"></div><div class="mejs-volume-current" style="height: 80px; top: 28px;"></div><div class="mejs-volume-handle" style="top: 25px;"></div></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-button mejs-fullscreen-button">
                        <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Schermo intero" aria-label="Schermo intero"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mejs-clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cont-video2" class="" style="max-height: 413px;">
    <div class=""> x </div>
    <div style="width: 640px; " class="wp-video">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script>document.createElement('video');</script><![endif]-->
        <span class="mejs-offscreen">Video Player</span>
        <div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container svg wp-video-shortcode mejs-video" tabindex="0" role="application" aria-label="Video Player" style="width: 640px; height: 360px;">
            <div class="mejs-inner">
                <div class="mejs-mediaelement">
                    <video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-219-1" width="640" height="360" preload="metadata" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4?_=1">
                        <source type="video/mp4" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4?_=1"><a href="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4</a>
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div class="mejs-layers">
                    <div class="mejs-poster mejs-layer" style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
                    <div class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
                        <div class="mejs-overlay-loading"><span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer" style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                        <div class="mejs-overlay-error"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer mejs-overlay-play" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                        <div class="mejs-overlay-button"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mejs-controls" style="display: block; visibility: hidden;">
                    <div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-play">
                        <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-time mejs-currenttime-container" role="timer" aria-live="off"><span class="mejs-currenttime">00:00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-time-rail" style="width: 496px;"><span class="mejs-time-total mejs-time-slider" style="width: 486px;"><span class="mejs-time-buffering" style="display: none;"></span><span class="mejs-time-loaded" style="width: 9.81818px;"></span><span class="mejs-time-current" style="width: 0px;"></span><span class="mejs-time-handle" style="left: -5px;"></span><span class="mejs-time-float"><span class="mejs-time-float-current">00:00</span><span class="mejs-time-float-corner"></span></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-time mejs-duration-container"><span class="mejs-duration">00:29</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-button mejs-volume-button mejs-mute">
                        <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Muto" aria-label="Muto"></button><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mejs-volume-slider" style="display: none;" aria-label="volumeSlider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuetext="80%" role="slider" tabindex="0"><span class="mejs-offscreen">Use Up/Down Arrow keys to increase or decrease volume.</span><div class="mejs-volume-total"></div><div class="mejs-volume-current" style="height: 80px; top: 28px;"></div><div class="mejs-volume-handle" style="top: 25px;"></div></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mejs-button mejs-fullscreen-button">
                        <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Schermo intero" aria-label="Schermo intero"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mejs-clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but if add to css `#cont-video2 {display:none;}` and then use a click action with jquery for open the video in a popup i see the video in large dimension
why this ?

**UPDATE**

I solved using  `position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px;` instead `display: none ;`and it work correctly.

Comment: Everything is bigger with jQuery ?

Comment: not only  jquery , also without popup , if load the page with display:none; and then remove display:none;(in chrome console) , the video not respect the video size in html declaration; if load page without display:none; the video have correct size